# Django sum values of a column after 'group by' in another column

Tags: django, django-models

I found some solutions here and in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/), but I could not manage to make one query work the way I wanted.

I have the following model:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    blindid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    massug = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to count the number of Blind_ID and then sum the massug after they were grouped.

My currently Django ORM

```
samples = Inventory.objects.values('blindid', 'massug').annotate(aliquots=Count('blindid'), total=Sum('massug'))
```

It's not counting correctly (it shows only one), thus it 's not summing correctly. It seems it is only getting the first result... I tried to use `Count('blindid', distinct=True)` and `Count('blindid', distinct=False)` as well.

This is the query result using `samples.query`. Django is grouping by the two columns...

```
SELECT "inventory"."blindid", "inventory"."massug", COUNT("inventory"."blindid") AS "aliquots", SUM("inventory"."massug") AS "total" FROM "inventory" GROUP BY "inventory"."blindid", "inventory"."massug"
```

This should be the raw sql

```
SELECT blindid, 
       Count(blindid) AS aliquots,
       Sum(massug) AS total
       FROM inventory 
       GROUP BY blindid
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
samples = Inventory.objects.values('blindid').annotate(aliquots=Count('blindid'), total=Sum('massug'))
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know I could select columns in the annotate field which were not previously in the query itself. Awesome... thanks!

Comment: This works great but what if i want to get the Inventory object instances instead of dicts?